# mv "Not a directory" when target name too long

Tags: filenames, samba

I'm trying to do an svn checkout on my local Ubuntu 14.04 LTS vagrant box (SSH via MTPutty):

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/shared/dev$ svn checkout https://...
[...]
svn: E000020: Can't move '/home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/.svn/tmp/svn-EGIIH6' to '/home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/twitterBootstrap3TranslatedView.html.twig': Not a directory
```

The directory exists though:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/shared/dev$ ls -al /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/
total 6
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 09:35 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 May 15 09:27 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   50 May 15 09:27 defaultTranslatedView.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   41 May 15 09:27 myView1.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   50 May 15 09:27 twitterBootstrap3View.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   49 May 15 09:27 twitterBootstrapView.html.twig
```

I then try to mv the file manually, which fails as well:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/shared/dev$ sudo mv /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/.svn/tmp/svn-EGIIH6 /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/twitterBootstrap3TranslatedView.html.twig
mv: cannot move ‘/home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/.svn/tmp/svn-EGIIH6’ to ‘/home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/twitterBootstrap3TranslatedView.html.twig’: Not a directory
```

If I shorten the filename though, the mv succeeds:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/shared/dev$ sudo mv /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/.svn/tmp/svn-EGIIH6 /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/twitter.html.twig
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/shared/dev$ ls -al  /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/trunk_new/htdocs/vendor/white-october/pagerfanta-bundle/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaBundle/TestsProject/src/WhiteOctober/PagerfantaTestBundle/Resources/views/Pagerfanta/
total 7
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 4096 May 15 09:33 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant    0 May 15 09:27 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   50 May 15 09:27 defaultTranslatedView.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   41 May 15 09:27 myView1.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   50 May 15 09:27 twitterBootstrap3View.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   49 May 15 09:27 twitterBootstrapView.html.twig
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant   61 May 15 09:27 twitter.html.twig
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:

@Stéphane Chazelas
Wow, I totally hadn't thought of that. I'm trying to do the svn checkout in the shared directory. The filename is simply too long for NTFS and, since it's synced between host and guest, the mv fails. Cheers mate.

Second Edit:

@Stéphane Chazelas
The shared directory used to reside inside my User folder on my local drive (`C:\Users\benjamin.franke\Documents\Vagrant\data`). 
Moving the folder to `C:\dev` allowed me to successfully perform the svn checkout on one repository, but fails with another which contains a file with an even longer path.

My Vagrantfile synced folder entry looks like this:

```
 config.vm.synced_folder "C:/dev", "/home/vagrant/shared", :mount_options => ["dmode=775","fmode=664"]
```

I might give this a shot https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/5495 and will post feedback.

Comment: Why would it assume *.twig is a directory? Why does it work fine, if I shorten the filename from `twitterBootstrap3TranslatedView.html.twig` to `twitter.html.twig`?

Comment: Please provide `ls -ld /home/vagrant/shared/dev/svv/.svn/tmp/svn-EGIIH6`. I think you may find it's a directory, which you cannot install on top of (or into) an existing file.

Comment: What file system is it? NTFS?

Comment: I suppose the issue is not as much NTFS (which should be able to store that path), but a Windows machine service that directory over CIFS. Is it?